# Ruby compare hash values by the same keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Let's say i have 3 hashes

```
hash1 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
hash2 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 3}
hash3 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 4, 'd' => 3}
hash4 = {'c' => 4, 'd' => 3, 'e' = 5}
```

Expected result

```
hash1 == hash2 # => true
hash1 == hash3 # => true
hash1 == hash4 # => false (has no common keys to compare their values)
hash2 == hash3 # => true
```

So basically i want to compare values of the same keys in both hashes while comparing. And give false if there are no common keys

Edit:
Tips to @CarySwoveland, his solution works perfectly:

```
common_keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys;

    if common_keys.any?
      hash1.values_at(*common_keys) == hash2.values_at(*common_keys);
    else
      false
    end
```

Comment: Do you need a method for it, ex `test(hash1, hash2)` or override `==`?

Comment: @razvans it's better to have a method for it, rather than monkeypatching

Comment: Try this: `common_keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys; hash1.values_at(*common_keys) == hash2.values_at(*common_keys)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it depends on any specific order?

Comment: Danyil, that will work even if the keys in the two hashes are ordered differently. I guess you need `common_keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys; if common_keys.any?; hash1.values_at(*common_keys) == hash2.values_at(*common_keys); else false; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank's a lot! That's exactly what i needed!

Comment: @Danyil - Minor, but you could just wirte `common_keys.any? && hash1.values_at(*common_keys) == [...]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-intersection), if I get the answer properly, and check if the first hash is included in the second:

```
require 'set'

def is_included?(hash_a, hash_b)
  return hash_a.size == (hash_a.to_set & hash_b.to_set).size
end
```

So, you can check this way:

```
hash1 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
hash2 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 3}
hash3 = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 4, 'd' => 3}
hash4 = {'c' => 4, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 5}

is_included?(hash1, hash2) #=> true
is_included?(hash1, hash3) #=> true
is_included?(hash1, hash4) #=> false
is_included?(hash2, hash3) #=> true
```

---

Also just `return hash_a.to_set <= hash_b.to_set` should work.

Comment: If `first = { a:1, b:2 }` and `second` = { c:3, a:1 }` your method returns `false`, yet `first[:a] == second[:a] #=> true`, `:a` being the only key common to both hashes.

Comment: You're right. I just checked for the expected result. Even if I change to `return (hash_a.to_set & hash_b.to_set).any?` to match your example, I'm in doubt about the expected result of `hash3` vs `hash4`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this solution is not working for some cases not mentioned in the original question, so this answer should fit better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69280216/299774

This formula will give you what you want (for the provided examples)

```
def compare(first, second)
  ((first.to_a & second.to_a) <=> first.to_a) >= 0
end
```

How does it work?

It transforms hashes into array of key-value pairs (also arrays)

```
> hash1.to_a
=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

So now you can do neat things, treat arrays as sets and find their intersections (the common elements):

```
> hash1.to_a & hash2.to_a
=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
> hash1.to_a & hash4.to_a
=> []
```

What is left, is to check if the intersection is included in one of those arrays, the rocket method `<=>` is very useful, will give you 0 when arrays are identical, 1 if the right one is included in the left one, and -1 otherwise. You seem to be interested in the first two cases, hence `>= 0`

Comment: If `first = { a:1, b:2 }` and `second = { c:3, a:1 }` your method returns `false`, yet `first[:a] == second[:a] #=> true`, `:a` being the only key common to both hashes.

Comment: That's true, @iGian's answer is much better https://stackoverflow.com/a/69280216/299774 and should be accepted (added a note on top to this one).